# Clickable modifier not working in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to implement an extension function on Modifier that would easily allow me to set a click action to a composable that would copy a specific text to the clipboard:

Here it is:

```
/**
 * @param textCopied Text to be copied to the clipboard.
 * @param clipLabel Label to identify the textCopied. Can be null.
 *
 * Android 13 shows a message when text has been copied to the clipboard natively, so we don't need to user that it has happened to avoid duplicate messages.
 * This method copies the given textCopied to the clipboard and shows a toast if the user is on an Android version lower than 13.
 * More info on: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/copy-paste#duplicate-notifications
 * */
fun Context.copyTextToClipboardAndNotify(textCopied: String, clipLabel: String? = null) {
    val clipboardManager = getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
    // When setting the clipboard text.
    clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText(clipLabel, textCopied))
    // Only show a toast for Android 12 and lower.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.S_V2)
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.text_copied_to_clipboard_S, textCopied), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

/**
 * @param textToCopy Text to be copied when composable is clicked.
 *
 * Sets a click action to the composable to copy the provided textToCopy to the clipboard.
 */
fun Modifier.copyOnClick(textToCopy: String?) = composed {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    textToCopy?.let {
        clickable {
            context.copyTextToClipboardAndNotify(it)
        }
    }
    this
}
```

And this is how I use it in the view:

```
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.copyOnClick(username),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) { 
        // Column content here
      }
```

This is not working at all though. When debugging, I can see that the debugger stops at the `clickable{}` breakpoint but never really enters the function when I click the view.

So, to try it out, I changed my view to

```
        val context = LocalContext.current
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.clickable { context.copyTextToClipboardAndNotify(username) },
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
           // Column content here
          }
```

And this worked! But it's obviously way less clean than what I want to achieve.

Why is my function not working properly? I suspect it's something with this `composed` function that they recommend using with Modifiers factories. I don't know exactly what it's doing, but seems to be messing things up. But I need it to access the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun Modifier.copyOnClick(textToCopy: String?) = composed {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    textToCopy?.let {
        clickable {
            context.copyTextToClipboardAndNotify(it)
        }
    }
    this
}
```

problem is you always return Modifier, never the clickable. Returning based on null check should solve the issue.

```
fun Modifier.copyOnClick(textToCopy: String?) = composed {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    textToCopy?.let {
        clickable {
            context.copyTextToClipboardAndNotify(it)
        }
    }?:this
   
}
```

Comment: That did it! Cannot believe this was the issue ‍♂️
Thanks a lot!